# How can I save scrape data in a CSV file

Tags: python, json, csv, web-scraping, python-requests

Hi I need help saving this data in a csv file, here is my code:

```
with open("keyword.txt") as f:
   keywords = f.read().splitlines()

# Filter similar sold domains by sale price and year

for domain in keywords:
   # Call appraisl API
   appraisal_res = requests.get(appraisal.format(domain), headers=headers).json()
   try:
      # Get appraisal and similar sold domains
      govalue = appraisal_res["govalue"]
      comparable_sales = appraisal_res["comparable_sales"]
      
   except:
      print(appraisal_res)
      
      continue
   # Filter by min appraisal price
   if govalue >= min_appr_price:
      print("{:30} : {}".format(domain, govalue))
      
   for sale in comparable_sales:
      # Filter similar sold domains by price and year
      if sale["price"] >= min_sale_price and sale["year"] >= min_sale_year:
         similar_domain = "{:30} : {:10} : {:10}".format(sale["domain"], sale["price"], sale["year"])
         # Do not include duplicates
         if similar_domain not in similar_domains:
            similar_domains.append(similar_domain)
   # Do not abuse the API
   time.sleep(2)
 
# Print similar sold domains
print("--------------------------------------------------------")
for domain in similar_domains:
   print(domain)
print("--------------------------------------------------------")
```

the data contains two parts:

1. govalue wish contain (domain wanted from .txt file, the value of this domain)
2. comparable sales (similar domains of the domain wanted, each has elements (domain, price, year))

So what I want is to save the data in this order:
for govalue .format(domain, govalue))

- Row 1: domain
- Row 2: govalue

for similar domain .format(sale["domain"], sale["price"], sale["year"])

- Row 3: sale domain
- Row 4: sale (price)
- Row 5: sale (year)
- Row 6: second sale domain
- Row 7: second sale price
- Row 8: second sale year
- row 9: third
- ...
  THE OUTPUT BE LIKE

```
best.com                       : 25000
--------------------------------------------------------
best.careers                   :        400 :       2021
best.casino                    :      25000 :       2022
best.cc                        :       1625 :       2017
best.ch                        :      14535 :       2007
best.club                      :       1000 :       2017
best.com                       :      25000 :       2009
best.com.es                    :       3591 :       2013
best.creditcard                :      10900 :       2017
best.es                        :       1549 :       2012
best.info                      :      20880 :       2005
--------------------------------------------------------
[Finished in 3.4s]
```

any suggestions please?

requests, json, csv, python

Comment: Have you tried using python's [csv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) module?

Comment: Yeah but I don't know how to integrate it in the code